# Reduce the usage of TIME_TICK when SCREEN_OFF?

Tags: android, time, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an `appwidget` on `HOME` which updates every minute. I can use `TIME_TICK` or `AlarmManager`, but this is not the point I am asking. The updates can be skipped if user is not looking at the `HOME`, as long as when `HOME` is displayed the info is the latest. So I am thinking of unregistering the `TIME_TICK` or cancelling the `AlarmManager` when the screen is off, and re-register or re-establish the `alarm` when the screen is on again. But I am not sure if the system resources saved justify the efforts in developing the logic and the processing required to on/off the `receiver`/`alarm`. What do you think?

I also want to do the same when my `appwidget`/`HOME` is at the *background*, but I don't know how to detect this at my `appwidget` logic. Please help.